# Dynamically generated html using Javascript object does not pick up Bootstrap or CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to generate and insert some new html into my webpage on clicking a button as such.

```
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function(event){        


        // Get number of steps user has typed in
        steps = document.getElementById("steps").value; 
        console.log(steps); 

        if (steps == ""){

            alert("Please provide number of synthetic steps");
        }        

        // Once click generate button, delete it and steps field to prevent being clicked again.         
        if (steps != ""){            

            // Array of elements wish to remove
            var removal = ["#steps", "#generate", "#field-wrap"]; 

            for (var i in removal){            

                $(removal[i]).remove();

            }    

            var page = new pages(steps);

            // Obtain html to show in first wrapper 
            var initial_html = page.initial(); 


            // Put initial html after first box id
            $('#wrapper').append(initial_html);            

      }
});
```

The page is styled using Bootstrap and I know the static content all works fine with this. The new html content is generated from the Javascript object, "pages":

```
function pages(step){            

    this.step = step; 

    // Function to insert in JME window. Note, had to change id to 

jsme_container1 in html and script to enable function to place canvas in correct position.            

    this.draw = function jsmeOnLoad () {                

        document.JME2 = new JSApplet.JSME("jsme_container1", "300px", "250px");            


        // Add identifier to JME object 
        document.JME2["step"] = this.step; 

        // Push on to global array
        drawing_objects.push(document.JME2);                 

    }

    // html to display in place of generate button for first JME object 
    this.initial = function(){

        return "<div id=‘field-wrap’><div id=‘button’><div class='form-groups' style='padding-bottom:5px;'><input autocomplete='off' autofocus class='form-control' name='Quantity'placeholder='Quantity required' type='text' id='quantity' style='width:150px;'/></div><div class=‘dropdown’ style='position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;'><button class=‘btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle’ id=‘touch’ type=‘button’ data-toggle=‘dropdown’>grams <span class=‘caret’></span></button><ul class=‘dropdown-menu’ id=‘menu’><li><a href=‘#’>milligrams</a></li> <li><a href=‘#’>grams</a></li><li><a href=‘#’>kilograms</a></li></ul></div></div> <form role=‘form’> <div class=‘form-group’><input type='text' class=‘form-control input-sm’ id=‘moles_start’ autocomplete='off' class='0' autofocus class='form-control' name='moles' placeholder='Moles' readonly/></div> <div class=‘form-group’> <input type='text' class=‘form-control input-sm’ autocomplete='off' class='0' autofocus class='form-control' name='smiles' placeholder='Smiles' readonly/> </div> <div class=‘form-group’><input type='text' class=‘form-control input-sm’ autocomplete='off' class='0' autofocus class='form-control' name='MW' placeholder='Molecular Weight' readonly/></div></form></div>";  

    };

}
```

I find that the html is inserted into the document fine using the jQuery method "append()", however it is not styled at all like the rest of the document ie it does not seem to pick up and of the Bootstrap and/or document's own CSS. I was wondering if I could get some pointers as to why this might be? Thanks

Comment: does the generated html has all needed bootstrap classes set up? and fiddle would be nice. Btw. I think that " ’ " in html string is not a single quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep the issue is in quotes indeed. Look at how those class names and id's look in dev tools.

All you need is to find and replace those ‘bad’ quotes.

[image]

Comment: Yeah you guys are spot on, cheers. Basically, because the html string was so long I copied and pasted it into word and did find and replace " for ' in there... I guess that was a big mistake! I am using Brackets code editor and couldn't find a find and replace tool in that... unless I am mistaken?

Comment: omg. save yourself some trouble. never use Word for development. It add's tons of trash symbols. I use Sublime Text. https://www.sublimetext.com/3 It has all I need and more. But any descent code editor should be capable of performing search and replace.

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with the quotation marks of your returned html. You used `‘` and `’` instead of `'` a couple of times. Try this:

```
this.initial = function(){

    return "<div id='field-wrap'><div id='button'><div class='form-groups' style='padding-bottom:5px;'><input autocomplete='off' autofocus class='form-control' name='Quantity' placeholder='Quantity required' type='text' id='quantity' style='width:150px;'/></div><div class='dropdown' style='position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' id='touch' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>grams <span class='caret'></span></button><ul class='dropdown-menu' id='menu'><li><a href='#'>milligrams</a></li> <li><a href='#'>grams</a></li><li><a href='#'>kilograms</a></li></ul></div></div> <form role='form'> <div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' id='moles_start' autocomplete='off' class='0' autofocus class='form-control' name='moles' placeholder='Moles' readonly/></div> <div class='form-group'> <input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' autocomplete='off' class='0' autofocus class='form-control' name='smiles' placeholder='Smiles' readonly/> </div> <div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' autocomplete='off' class='0' autofocus class='form-control' name='MW' placeholder='Molecular Weight' readonly/></div></form></div>";  

};
```